# FilterChain throwing javax.servlet.ServletException: IteratedExpression.getItem: Index out of Bounds

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, servlet-filters

Apologies for the lack of a code example but I'm not sure I could replicate the issue in a simple example.

The exception below has started to appear recently in my RichFaces application. It is a web front end for querying a database and display the data in a simple table. The problem occurs when my application finishes executing my code on the bean linked to a command button. It calls FilterChain.doFilter when you click the button on the pop panel, then completes the code on the bean, then i assume while trying to rerender the main window this exception is thrown.

The problem appeared when a new entry point to this same popup panel that performs the same code on the bean when the button is clicked that works fine, however since this new entry point was added the old one has started throwing this exception.

I know it's unlikely anyone will be able to provide an answer to the problem without code but having little understanding of how these filter chains work, I am not even sure where to start looking and was wondering if anyone could point me in a direction that might lead me to finding a solution.

The service is running on WASCE 2.1.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: IteratedExpression.getItem: Index out of Bounds
at javax.faces.webapp._ErrorPageWriter.throwException(_ErrorPageWriter.java:549)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.handleLifecycleException(FacesServlet.java:293)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:187)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at myPackage.jsfutils.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at myPacakge.jsfutils.CheckLogonFilter.doFilter(CheckLogonFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.DefaultSubjectValve.invoke(DefaultSubjectValve.java:56)
at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:406)
at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.ThreadCleanerValve.invoke(ThreadCleanerValve.java:40)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: IteratedExpression.getItem: Index out of Bounds
at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.IteratedExpression.getItem(IteratedExpression.java:75)
at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.IteratedValueExpression.getValue(IteratedValueExpression.java:60)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:64)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:112)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:101)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:1081)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getValue(UIDataAdaptor.java:1624)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.getDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:65)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.createDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:59)
at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable.createDataModel(UIDataTable.java:120)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:621)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getRowIndex(UIDataAdaptor.java:311)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.idsAreEqual(_ComponentUtils.java:134)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.findComponent(_ComponentUtils.java:110)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.findComponent(_ComponentUtils.java:107)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.findComponent(_ComponentUtils.java:107)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.findComponent(_ComponentUtils.java:107)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:449)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:912)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:919)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:919)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:919)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findComponentFor(RendererUtils.java:882)
at org.ajax4jsf.context.AjaxContextImpl.convertId(AjaxContextImpl.java:395)
at org.ajax4jsf.context.AjaxContextImpl.addRegionsFromComponent(AjaxContextImpl.java:331)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.setupReRender(AjaxActionComponent.java:96)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:60)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIInclude.broadcast(UIInclude.java:170)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastAjaxEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:340)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.processAjaxEvents(AjaxViewHandler.java:216)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:169)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:140)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:182)
... 29 more
2011-12-12 16:35:48,342 ERROR [[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: IteratedExpression.getItem: Index out of Bounds
at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.IteratedExpression.getItem(IteratedExpression.java:75)
at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.IteratedValueExpression.getValue(IteratedValueExpression.java:60)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:64)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:112)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:101)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:1081)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getValue(UIDataAdaptor.java:1624)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.getDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:65)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.createDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:59)
at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable.createDataModel(UIDataTable.java:120)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getExtendedDataModel(UIDataAdaptor.java:621)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getRowIndex(UIDataAdaptor.java:311)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.idsAreEqual(_ComponentUtils.java:134)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.findComponent(_ComponentUtils.java:110)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.findComponent(_ComponentUtils.java:107)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.findComponent(_ComponentUtils.java:107)
at javax.faces.component._ComponentUtils.findComponent(_ComponentUtils.java:107)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.findComponent(UIComponentBase.java:449)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:912)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:919)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:919)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findUIComponentBelow(RendererUtils.java:919)
at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererUtils.findComponentFor(RendererUtils.java:882)
at org.ajax4jsf.context.AjaxContextImpl.convertId(AjaxContextImpl.java:395)
at org.ajax4jsf.context.AjaxContextImpl.addRegionsFromComponent(AjaxContextImpl.java:331)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.setupReRender(AjaxActionComponent.java:96)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:60)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIInclude.broadcast(UIInclude.java:170)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:321)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastAjaxEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:340)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.processAjaxEvents(AjaxViewHandler.java:216)
at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:169)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:140)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:182)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at myPackage.jsfutils.HibernateSessionRequestFilter.doFilter(HibernateSessionRequestFilter.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at myPackage.jsfutils.CheckLogonFilter.doFilter(CheckLogonFilter.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.DefaultSubjectValve.invoke(DefaultSubjectValve.java:56)
at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.GeronimoStandardContext$SystemMethodValve.invoke(GeronimoStandardContext.java:406)
at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.invoke(GeronimoBeforeAfterValve.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
at org.apache.geronimo.tomcat.valve.ThreadCleanerValve.invoke(ThreadCleanerValve.java:40)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Looking at the code for the getItem method it appears it is trying to iterate over a list object which could be of type collection, iterator, enumeration, map or string up to the index i passed into the method. This "originalListObject" is a value on a ValueExpression mapped to an ELContext. So does anyone have any idea on what might cause this method to pass an index value not in the originalListObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved was trying to rerender part of the panel that didn't exist. Strange how it only happened on the one entry point was in the jsp as a rerender attribute on the confirm button on the popup panel so both entry points where using the same button and jsp declaration. Added in the part that was missing as it was meant to be there and can only imagine it was removed by mistake or an svn merge.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the root cause:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: IteratedExpression.getItem: Index out of Bounds
at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.IteratedExpression.getItem(IteratedExpression.java:75)
at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.IteratedValueExpression.getValue(IteratedValueExpression.java:60)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:64)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:112)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:101)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:1081)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.UIDataAdaptor.getValue(UIDataAdaptor.java:1624)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.getDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:65)
at org.ajax4jsf.component.SequenceDataAdaptor.createDataModel(SequenceDataAdaptor.java:59)
at org.richfaces.component.UIDataTable.createDataModel(UIDataTable.java:120)
...
```

This is absolutely not related to filters. The request just happens to being passed through a filter. If the filter would have caused any problem, you would have seen it in the 1st line of the stacktrace.

Your concrete problem is most likely caused by not preserving the proper data model for the data table in the subsequent request. The managed bean is apparently in the request scope instead of the view scope. To fix this, you need to put the bean in the view scope and if necessary review your data model preserving/preloading logic. This should take place in (post)constructor and/or (action)listener methods, but for sure not in the getter method. The getter method should **only** return the data model, nothing more.

If you are still on JSF 1.x which doesn't have the new JSF 2.x view scope, you need to add an `<a4j:keepAlive>` to the page which references the request scoped managed bean.

Comment: All of my beans are in the session scope and i am using jsf 1.2. The data model is a standard richfaces data model using the <rich:dataTable> tags. Perhaps I haven't completely understood your answer but if this was the case why would the exact same jsp page and managed bean work when I come through the new entry point and not through the old one. Also before the new entry point to this popup panel was added the old one also worked fine.

Comment: I also mentioned the filter as this is the last place this touches any of my code the rest is all from various external jars used by richfaces